# SCSS назначение свойств по условию

Tags: html, css, scss, условия

Уточните пожалуйста, возможно назначить свойства внешнему классу по условию наличия внутри определенного класса. Пример:
Нужно назначить свойства классу class="g-grid" если внутри есть класс Test1

```css
<div class="g-container">                                
<div class="g-grid">                        
    <div class="Test1">
            
  </div>
</div>
<div class="g-grid">
    <div class="Test2">
            
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Селекторы для родителя относительно ребенка в css не существуют. Возможные варианты:

1 - Если нужно проверить только на наличие дочерних элементов, то в css можно использовать псевдокласс `:empty`.

2 - Добавляйте классы к родителю.

3 - Находите с помощью js.

Answer (score 0):

решение оказалось проще`selector:nth-child(an+b){ properties }`